# Navigating to horizontally laid out content held within a div with overflow set to hidden

Tags: jquery

I've got three menu links that I would like to have navigate horizontally to three various sections inside a container div that is set to overflow hidden.

What I have so far only allows me to scroll to the far right of the div but won't move again when I click on another menu link.

The script was adapted from ScrollTop which works well on html, body but doesn't work the same with ScrollLeft on the targeted divs.

My thinking was that since this worked vertically on the entire page I could tweak it to work on a targeted area to operate horizontally but so far this isn't the case. If anyone could help me work this out it would be very helpful.

```
<menu  id="portfolio-nav">

    <a href="#design-industrial">
    </a>

    <a href="#design-print">
    </a>

    <a href="#design-photography">
    </a>    

</menu>

<div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="portfolio-horizontal-wrapper">

        <div id="design-industrial" class="portfolio-content"> 
        </div>

        <div id="design-print" class="portfolio-content"> 
        </div>

        <div id="design-photography" class="portfolio-content"> 
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<style>

.portfolio-container {
    width: 260px; 
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.portfolio-horizontal-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.portfolio-content {
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

             $('.portfolio-container, .portfolio-horizontal-wrapper').animate({
                'scrollLeft': $target.offset().left -62}, 1111, 'swing', function () {        
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What's `.start()`? And minor typo in your CSS, `Height: 100%;` should be `height: 100%;`.

Comment: I removed start() ...I can't explain why that was there. I've fixed the typo. @j08691 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you want an explanation of why it wasn't working or just working code...
the MAIN issue would be the use of `position()` vs `offset()`.  Also setting the `.portfolio-horizontal-wrapper` element to `position: relative` in the CSS helps the JQuery to get the proper ***current*** x-position of the element you want to target.... anyway, if thats too confusing *or* doesn't make sense ***or*** you dont care :).... here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80PoundsOfFury/wb3gA/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Despite my vague-ish question you managed to pull out a direct answer. I will never take position:relative for granted ever again! Thanks!